# Установить php 5.6 на xampp - windows 2003

Tags: php, xampp

Всем привет. Есть VPS сервер на windows 2003. Хотел установить на него xampp с php 5.6.3, но:

> Windows XP or 2003 are not supported. You can download a compatible
>   version of XAMPP for these platforms here.

При переходе по ссылке, он открывает sourceforge с версиями xampp php 5.4 максимум.

Установил xampp с 5.4, скачал php 5.6.3, поставил в папку php - сервер выдает ошибку. Посмотрел, что для него нужен visual studio, поставил, тот же итог. Что делать? Как поставить на win2003 xampp с php 5.6.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разработчики дают Вам понять, что ни XP, ни 2003 больше не поддерживаются. К слову, даже Open Server сейчас не поддерживает Windows ниже 7.

Лично я вижу два возможных выхода из положения:

- Попытаться установить PHP на Windows в соответствии со стандартными руководствами;
- Попытаться собрать XAMPP с нужными компонентами самостоятельно (благо XAMPP, это open source проект).